# Configure makefile for debug and release targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Considering a Makefile similar to the following:

```
CC = gcc
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

SRCDIR = .
OBJECTS = \
    file1.o \
    file2.o \
    file3.o
THREADS = 1


all: release

release: CXXFLAGS += -DNUM_THREADS=$(THREADS)
release: main

debug: CXXFLAGS += -g -DDEBUG -DVERBOSENESS=3 -DNUM_THREADS=$(THREADS)
debug: main

# Build main executable...
main: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

# Compile all object files...
file1.o: $(SRCDIR)/file1.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^
file2.o: $(SRCDIR)/file2.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^
file3.o: $(SRCDIR)/file3.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^
```

This works properly only for the first `make`: using other words, object files are not recompiled when I launch `make` with a different target respect to the previous one.
That said, how could I make the object files recompile if I change between `debug` or `release` target?

Comment: There is no simple way to do this.  Generally, doing it requires that you have a rule that writes out the compile options to a file, then have all the object files depend on that file.  The more common method is to have your makefile generate object files in subdirectories like debug/file1.o or release/file1.o so they don't interfere with each other.

Comment: You can use `-B` switch to force recompilation as needed. But this makes sense only if you switch targets rarely. So supporting two build directories is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force recompilation strictly based on one label, say "Debug" *vs*. "Release", then you can do it by writing and depending on appropriate timestamp files, like so:

```
TYPE = Debug

#
# ... conditional settings based on $(TYPE) ...
#

OBJS = prog.o

all: test

prog: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS)

$(OBJS): $(TYPE)-mode-stamp

$(TYPE)-mode-stamp: last-mode-stamp
    touch $@
    touch -r $@ last-mode-stamp

last-mode-stamp:
    touch $@

clean:
    @rm *-mode-stamp $(OBJS) prog
```

That supposes you select the build type by setting variable `$(TYPE)`, possibly via the command line.  All the object files have `$(TYPE)-mode-stamp` as a prerequisite, so if that file is out of date then all of them will be rebuilt, along with anything that has any of them as a prerequisite.  `$(TYPE)-mode-stamp` itself has `last-mode-stamp` as a prerequisite, so the former is updated if it is older than the latter, or if the latter itself is out of date.  The recipe for `$(TYPE)-mode-stamp` sets both files timestamps to the current time, so that

1. `$(TYPE)-mode-stamp` is no longer out of date with respect to `last-mode-stamp`, and
2. `last-mode-stamp` is newer than any OtherType-mode-stamp that may be present.

A rule without any prerequisites (but *with* a recipe) creates `last-mode-stamp` if it does not initially exist.

Note well that this is altogether different from and orthogonal to monitoring whether any build tools or flags change.